# CakePHP find method crashes on live server when more than a few entries

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, crash, find

I'm encountering a strange error in CakePHP and I have no idea how to figure out what is going on. 
I am using a Ajax request to load dynamic data for a dataTable and it works perfectly on my localhost. For some reason I can't get it to work on my live server when I have more than a few entries. 
After debugging I found that it's the find function that is not working. When I have more than a few entries in my response array than one of the arrays('SollProject') is just simply completely empty and the whole script stops working.

Here is my Code:

```
        $project = $this->Project->find("first", array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$project_id) ,
                        'contain' => array(
                            'SollProject' => array(
                                'conditions'=> array(
                                    'SollProject.date >=' => $year.'-01-01',
                                    'SollProject.date <=' => $year.'-12-31'
                                )
                            ),
                            'HabenProject'=> array(
                                'conditions'=> array(
                                    'HabenProject.date >=' => $year.'-01-01',
                                    'HabenProject.date <=' => $year.'-12-31'
                                )
                            ))));
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here or why it is not working on the live server? There is no afterFind method in case you were wondering.

Maybe I should mention that I tried error debugging already and I don't get any error messages. I also tried the same sql code on my sql server and it works perfectly. There is also no memory issues since the memory I'm using is way beyound what I'm usually using and it's only a json response. 
The function itself also works for small entries (not more than maybe 5 entries) but as soon as I have a little bit more entries in the database it just crashes.

The interesting thing is that I can `debug($project['HabenProject'])` and it shows me all HabenProject but if I try `debug($project['SollProject'])` or just `debug($project)` the variable is just empty. It's not even declared as array. There is just no output. The rest of the page is still showing.

Comment: Please post the query that it's built.

Comment: use `<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>` in you layout and copy the query and run it on `mysql` you will have an better idea.

Comment: sql_dump is completely empty, and the query is  
SELECT `SollProject`.`id`, `SollProject`.`date`, `SollProject`.`soll_ab`, `SollProject`.`haben_ab`, `SollProject`.`buchungsbetrag`, `SollProject`.`buchungstext`, `SollProject`.`belegart`, `SollProject`.`belegnummer` FROM `db397231557`.`project_transactions` AS `SollProject` WHERE `SollProject`.`date` >= '2015-01-01' AND `SollProject`.`date` <= '2015-12-31' AND `SollProject`.`soll_ab` = (40865) ORDER BY `SollProject`.`date`

Answer (score 0):

Basic debugging steps:

- Set debug to 2
- Check your CakePHP apps logs
- Check the php logs
- Check the webserver logs

However, I guess it's a memory limit and debug is off, that's probably why you get a white page. Check the memory usage and increase the php memory limit.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not completely stupid... 
I set debug already to 2, no error or anything showing. Unfortunately I can't check any server logs cause I don't have any rights to do so cause I'm working on this crappy Webserver where I can't access any deeper server information... 
I checked the memory usage on my localhost and it's completely normal. It's a big page and the memory limit is already pretty high and the data I'm requesting is small in comparison to what I'm doing on the page...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after lots of debugging it looks like I found the problem: 
For some reason every entry with an Umlaut (äüö) in the database produced an error that caused the result array of the find function to not work anymore. 
Turns out the problem was the live server database utf-8 encryption was commented off...